# Different Messages For Different User Inputs

Tags: ruby

How do I put a message (string) for a specific answer (user input) and another message for another answer? For e.g.

```
puts "Did You Like My Program?"
feedback = gets

if feedback = "Yes"
  puts "We're Glad!"
elsif feedback = "No"
  puts "We Will Try To Improve!"
end
```

What should I change, add, or modify?

Comment: `feedback = gets.chomp`. And `feedback == "Yes"`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, when you compare, you have to use [`==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-3D-3D), not `=`.

When you input on command line, you always use <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It produces `\n` at the end of the string. So you need to remove it with [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-chomp).

Also, to filter user input, I suggest this variant:

```
feedback = nil

until %w[y n].include?(feedback)
  puts 'Did You Like My Program? Y/N'
  feedback = gets.chomp.downcase
end

if feedback == 'y'
  puts "We're Glad!"
else
  puts "We Will Try To Improve!"
end
```

Brief explanation:

- The code uses [`Array#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) and [`String#downcase`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-downcase).
- `%w[y n]` is equal to `["y", "n"]`.
- The `until`-loop executes the code while the condition is `false`.